# Parsing Json file and create Hashmap<k,v>

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am finding a solution for get each single key value of a JSONObject dynamicaly.
I have a JSON file like this:

```
{  
   "RESPONSE":{  
      "A":"test",
      "B":{  
         "C":"0",
         "D":"1"
      },
      "E":{  
         "F":"2",
         "G":"3"
      }
   }
}
```

I wish to create a Hashmap that contains the key and the value of the objects, like this example:

legend:
key = value

```
"A" = "test"  
"B" = "{"C":"0", "D":"1"}"   
"B.C" = "0"  
"B.D" = "1"  
"E" = "{"F":"2","G":"3"}"  
"E.F" = "2"
"E.G" = "3"
```

I have tried writing this code:

```
private static HashMap<String, Object> createJsonObjectsHashMapOfConfigFile(String jsonFilePath,
        String JsonObjectToIterate) throws Exception {

    HashMap<String, Object> jHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    JSONObject jsonConfigFile = SimulatorUtil.readJsonFromFile(jsonFilePath); // Returns the Json file
    JSONObject jsonConfigObj = jsonConfigFile.getJSONObject(JsonObjectToIterate); // JsonObjectToIterate -->
                                                                                    // "RESPONSE"
    Iterator<?> configIter = jsonConfigObj.keys();
    String currentDynamicKey = "";

    while (configIter.hasNext()) {
        currentDynamicKey = (String) configIter.next();
        Object currentDynamicValue = jsonConfigObj.get(currentDynamicKey);
        jHashMap.put(currentDynamicKey, currentDynamicValue);
        logger.info(" ---> " + jHashMap.toString());

    }

    return jHashMap;
}
```

but it get only the first level key ("A", "B", "E").
I must use org.json.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks,
Luca

Comment: You might want to see if a key has children and loop on them if it's the case

Comment: Yes the scope in this